# ExtJS 5 grid filtering and sorting breaks in IE9

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, extjs, extjs5

I am trying to add filtering to a simple ExtJS 5 Grid. I am using a simple example provided by the installation and looks like it is working fine, except in IE when I try to do filtering all the records get wiped.

Has anyone seen this issue? Here is the code that I am using.

`$("#SearchEmployees").click(function () {

```
var criteria = $("#employeeName").val();

if (criteria == '' || criteria == null) {
    alert("Please apply search criteria.");
    return;
}

var baseurl = $("#hdnUrlSearch").val();

var data = (function () {

    $("#employeesSearchGrid").empty();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: baseurl,
        dataType: "json",
        data: { employeeName: criteria },
        async: false
    }).done(function (retData) {
        data = retData;
    }).fail(function (xhr) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    });

    return data;
})();

Ext.define('EmployeeSearch', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        'FullName',
        'DepartmentName',
        'PhoneNumber',
        'EmailAddr'
    ]
});


var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'EmployeeSearch',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax'          
    },
    data: data
});

var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    store: store,
    forceFit: true,
    columns: [{
        header: 'Name',
        dataIndex: 'FullName',
        flex: 1,
        filter: 'string',
        width: 440
    }, {
        header: 'Department',
        dataIndex: 'DepartmentName',
        filter: 'string',
        flex: 1,
        width: 200
    }, {
        header: 'Direct Phone',
        dataIndex: 'PhoneNumber',
        filter: 'string',
        flex: 1,
        width: 240
    }, {
        header: 'Notification Email',
        dataIndex: 'EmailAddr',
        flex: 1,
        filter: 'string'
    }],
    renderTo: 'employeesSearchGrid',
    frame: true,
    plugins: ['gridfilters']
});
```

});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was fixed by adding height of the grid. Once I did that filtering and sorting got fixed. Here is how my grid looks like now:

```
 var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    store: store,       
    columns: [{
        text: 'Name',
        dataIndex: 'FullName',            
        flex: 1,
        width: 440,
        sortable: true,
        filter: 'string'
    }, {
        text: 'Department',
        dataIndex: 'DepartmentName',
        flex: 1,
        width: 200,
        sortable: true,
        filter: 'string'
    }, {
        text: 'Direct Phone',
        dataIndex: 'PhoneNumber',
        flex: 1,
        width: 240,
        sortable: true,
        filter: 'string'
    }, {
        text: 'Notification Email',
        dataIndex: 'EmailAddr',
        flex: 1,
        sortable: true,
        filter: 'string'
    }],
    forceFit: true,
    split: true,
    renderTo: 'employeesSearchGrid',
    height: 210,
    frame: true,
    plugins: ['gridfilters']
});
```